# converting XMLHTTPRequest To jquery ajax

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, xmlhttprequest

I try lots of ways to convert my XMLHTTPRequest into jQuery ajax but I couldn't be successful.

I would be really appreciate if anyone could help me solve this issue.

here is my XMLHttpRequest Code:

```
    var url = url;
    var xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    xhr.open("POST", url);    
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
       if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
           console.log(xhr.status);
           console.log(xhr.responseText);
    }};
    
    var data = "ajax=1";  
    xhr.send(data);
```

and here is my attempt but its not working

```
$.ajax({
             url: "<?php echo $this->ui_url('onlineexamcats', 'all'); ?>",
             data: JSON.stringify("ajax=1"),
             type: "POST",
             processData: false,
             contentType: false,
             beforeSend: function(xhr){xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type',  "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");},
             success: function(res) { console.log(res); }
          });
```

Comment: What was your attempt? Should be straight forward. https://api.jquery.com/jquery.post/

Comment: I just edit my question you can see my ajax code @epascarello

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this

```
$.ajax({
    url: "<?php echo $this->ui_url('onlineexamcats', 'all'); ?>",
    data: "ajax=1",
    type: "POST",
    processData: false,
    success: function(res) { console.log(res); }
});
```

Comment: thanks but I need to post my data as raw string and contentType: "application/x-www-form-urlencoded"

Comment: @FarzaneKhazaei you mean you want to send the data as `ajax=1` instead of `{ajax: 1}`?

Comment: exactly! @ruleboy21

Comment: @FarzaneKhazaei I've updated my answer. Kindly check it out. Note that `application/x-www-form-urlencoded` is the default contentType that is why I ignored. But you can still set it manually if you like.